# Using only USB Type C signals without USB2.0 Signals

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c, usb-host, usb-hub

Need your help regarding [SC200E](https://www.quectel.com/product/lte-sc200e-smart-module-series) USB. As per my understanding SC200E supports both USB2.0 and USB Type C.

My question is can we use it separately.

I mean we need to connect the USB2.0 signals of SC200E to another
microcontroller(FS32K148UJT0VLQT) present in the other board

and we are planning to take out the type C signals to type C connector for programming the SC200E module.

Please see the below block diagram.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing USB-C and USB 3 SuperSpeed. "SuperSpeed" is what these "SS" in the signal names are for!

Can't have a standards-compliant USB 3 bus without USB 2 D+ and D-, simple as that; USB bus arbitration is based on that, so it plain wouldn't work with normal hardware.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake, Yes it is usb super speed.So we can't use USB2.0 separately. I am planning to use a USB switch in the path that can be enabled for debugging and programming.May I know your thoughts.

Comment: You can't use usb3 separately. You can certainly switch between different ushers of the USB 2 lines. A hub won't help you, as they can't switch the role of pets between upstream host and downstream devices.

Comment: I am planning to use USB switch on USB2.0 lines.I won't be using usb super speed in my board.Decided to go with only usb2.0